# Issue getting Github code to work on my own Jupyter Notebook

Tags: github, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am new to Python and would like your help please.

I am copying the NorthernBobwhiteCNN code from Github to try to use the program on my computer: https://github.com/GAMELab-UGA/NorthernBobwhiteCNN.  I cloned the Github files as my own Jupyter Notebook that I launched from the Command Prompt.

However, when I try to run the cells in [model_prediction_example.ipynb](https://github.com/GAMELab-UGA/NorthernBobwhiteCNN/blob/main/PythonCode/model_prediction_example.ipynb) after the import statement cell, I receive multiple errors for all the cells and the code won't run, even though everything is the exact same from Github.

Here are the errors I get using Load Trained Model cell:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 8>()
      4 model = net.Net(params).cuda() if torch.cuda.is_available() else net.Net(params)
      7 restore_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'pretrained.pth.tar')
----> 8 _ = utils.load_checkpoint(restore_path, model, optimizer=None)

File ~\NorthernBobwhiteCNN\PythonCode\utils.py:136, in load_checkpoint(checkpoint, model, optimizer)
    134 if not os.path.exists(checkpoint):
    135     raise("File doesn't exist {}".format(checkpoint))
--> 136 checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint)
    137 model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    139 if optimizer:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:789, in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, weights_only, **pickle_load_args)
    787             except RuntimeError as e:
    788                 raise pickle.UnpicklingError(UNSAFE_MESSAGE + str(e)) from None
--> 789         return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    790 if weights_only:
    791     try:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1131, in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1129 unpickler = UnpicklerWrapper(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1130 unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
-> 1131 result = unpickler.load()
   1133 torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()
   1135 return result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1101, in _load.<locals>.persistent_load(saved_id)
   1099 if key not in loaded_storages:
   1100     nbytes = numel * torch._utils._element_size(dtype)
-> 1101     load_tensor(dtype, nbytes, key, _maybe_decode_ascii(location))
   1103 return loaded_storages[key]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1083, in _load.<locals>.load_tensor(dtype, numel, key, location)
   1079 storage = zip_file.get_storage_from_record(name, numel, torch.UntypedStorage).storage().untyped()
   1080 # TODO: Once we decide to break serialization FC, we can
   1081 # stop wrapping with TypedStorage
   1082 loaded_storages[key] = torch.storage.TypedStorage(
-> 1083     wrap_storage=restore_location(storage, location),
   1084     dtype=dtype)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:215, in default_restore_location(storage, location)
    213 def default_restore_location(storage, location):
    214     for _, _, fn in _package_registry:
--> 215         result = fn(storage, location)
    216         if result is not None:
    217             return result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:182, in _cuda_deserialize(obj, location)
    180 def _cuda_deserialize(obj, location):
    181     if location.startswith('cuda'):
--> 182         device = validate_cuda_device(location)
    183         if getattr(obj, "_torch_load_uninitialized", False):
    184             with torch.cuda.device(device):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:166, in validate_cuda_device(location)
    163 device = torch.cuda._utils._get_device_index(location, True)
    165 if not torch.cuda.is_available():
--> 166     raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
    167                        'device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. '
    168                        'If you are running on a CPU-only machine, '
    169                        'please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device(\'cpu\') '
    170                        'to map your storages to the CPU.')
    171 device_count = torch.cuda.device_count()
    172 if device >= device_count:

RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

I think that the errors are due to incorrect or missing library installations on my virtual environment.

First, I created the virtual environment "bobwhite" using `conda create bobwhite` in my command prompt.

Then, I did multiple conda installations based on the import statements in the [model_prediction_example.ipynb](https://github.com/GAMELab-UGA/NorthernBobwhiteCNN/blob/main/PythonCode/model_prediction_example.ipynb).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
import torch
import utils
import model.net as net
```

So, I did the following installs in my command prompt:

```
conda install matplotlib
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
conda install numpy
conda install scipy
conda install scikit-image
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
conda install pip
pip install utils
```

However, I am not sure that I have installed the correct libraries to get the notebook to run.  How would I find out which libraries are needed based on the import statements? Would I also need to import the libraries used in the python code net.py and utils.py as well? Additionally, I do not understand the `import model.net as net` statement.  Is this referencing the net.py python script also found on the Github?  If so, would I need to use a conda install for that, and how would I do it?

Comment: The code is trying to load the model with CUDA. Since you're using I'm guessing that it isn't able to access your GPU or cuda isn't available.


Can you share the result of running just `import torch; torch.cuda.is_available()` in python?

Comment: The result of running torch.cuda.is_available() returns False.  I assume it needs to return True for the code to work.  However, my computer does not have a GPU so I installed pytorch using the command for CPU: conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch.  However, I see that in the local_context_norm.py, there is the line: device = torch.device(torch.cuda.current_device() if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu').  Doesn't this mean that the code could run on either CUDA or CPU?  And so it could run even though torch.cuda.is_available() is False?

Comment: It should work even if it returns False. `model = net.Net(params).cuda() if torch.cuda.is_available() else net.Net(params)` uses cuda only only if it returns True so it should work. Can you try changing that line to `model = net.Net(params)`

Comment: Changing the lane to model=net.Net(params) returns the same errors.  Would the error be in the other python files itself?

Answer (score 0):

Change [this](https://github.com/GAMELab-UGA/NorthernBobwhiteCNN/blob/f6871e5c2da9952c5ac7e2cdd5cf3fd4c9f22e30/PythonCode/utils.py#L136) line to

```py
map_location = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint, map_location=map_location)
```

The existing code is trying to load to cuda even if it is not available. This will make sure it loads to CPU if cuda is not available.

This part of your error's stacktrace points out the issue

```
File ~\NorthernBobwhiteCNN\PythonCode\utils.py:136, in load_checkpoint(checkpoint, model, optimizer)
    134 if not os.path.exists(checkpoint):
    135     raise("File doesn't exist {}".format(checkpoint))
--> 136 checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint)
    137 model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    139 if optimizer:
```